# Pandas modify value after first N True value

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the following to tables of boolean values:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'v': [True, True, True],
                         'w': [True, False, False], 
                         'x': [False, True, False],
                         'y': [True, True, True],
                         'z': [True, False, True]},
                         index=pd.Series([1, 2, 3], name='index'))
```

| index | v | w | x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | True | True | False | True | True |
| 2 | True | False | True | True | False |
| 3 | True | False | False | True | True |

After n first True values in each row, how can I turn rest of the values into False? For example, if n was 2:

| index | v | w | x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | True | True | False | False | False |
| 2 | True | False | True | False | False |
| 3 | True | False | False | True | False |

Row row 1, `x` and `y` would turn to `False`, since `v` and `w` are `True`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `where` and `cumsum`

```
n = 2
out = df1.where(df1.cumsum(axis=1)<=n,False)
Out[24]: 
          v      w      x      y      z
index                                  
1      True   True  False  False  False
2      True  False   True  False  False
3      True  False  False   True  False
```